# Missing symbol in brew-installed cartopy

Tags: macos, homebrew, cartopy

I am attempting to install Cartopy on a new MacBook Pro running Big Sur using homebrew. I've done the following:

- brew install proj
- brew install geos
- brew install pkg-config
- setenv PKG_CONFIG_PATH /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
- pip3 uninstall shapely
- pip3 install shapely --no-binary shapely
- pip3 install cartopy

This failed because it couldn't find proj_api.h. After manually setting CFLAGS to I/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Headers (which has the only copy of proj_api.h that I can find), installation succeeded. However... when I attempt to import cartopy in a python script, I get the following error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/__init__.py", line 104, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 22, in <module>
    from cartopy._crs import (CRS, Geodetic, Globe, PROJ4_VERSION,
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/_crs.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _pj_free
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/_crs.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/_crs.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong (other than failing to use conda to start with)?

Comment: You could try installing it with conda (as recomended)